# materializecss checkbox make page wider in some browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

hello this is my page in chrome and it's okay 
[image: chrome browser]

and same page with same code in mozilla 
how to fix this problem 
[image: mozilla]
in mozilla make my page so wide so it's make horizontal scroll

```html
<div class="row">
    {{--<p class="">--}}

      {{--<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="">--}}
      {{--<label for="checkbox">نظرررررر</label>--}}
    {{--</p>--}}
    <div class="switch">
    <label>نظر سنجی</label>
    <label>دارد
      <input type="checkbox" name="survey">
      <span class="lever"></span>ندارد
    </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: @Varin it's my code i put in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because i make every thing rtl in it's make this disaster

```
body {direction:rtl}
```

and code above mades this problem
so to fix it you must

```
body {direction : ltr}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can't do much without seeing the code... Try:

```
html, body {
  width:100%;
}
```